# is there a way to use an input file instead of stdin while debugging with VSlick?

Tags: c++, input, arguments, stdin

I am trying to debug a C++ program that accepts input from stdin (using getch()). I need to debug it using VSlick and an input file. I need something that would run as if i ran my program like so: myProgram < myInputFile

but obviously, within Vslick.

i tried using the '< myInputFile' as command line arguments but to no avail.

10x

Answer (score 0):

Here is something u can do

```
freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);  //For input from input.txt
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout); //for output to output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In Project properties (tools), you can define your command line for Debug and Execute.